# ($x=\sqrt[n] m ≠ x=m^\frac 1n $) when m is an even number

Tags: roots, exponentiation, common-root

**Note:** In this question I am using the radical symbol to denote **all** roots of a number, not just the positive one.

$$x=\sqrt[n] m ≠ x=m^\frac 1n $$ when m is an even number

for example:-
$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=±2$$
or:
$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=4^\frac 12$$
$$(x)^2=(4^\frac 12)^2$$
$$x^2 = 4^1$$
$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=±2$$

but:
$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=4^\frac 12$$
$$x=(2^2)^\frac 12$$
$$x=2^\frac 22$$
$$x=2^1$$
$$x=2$$

in above example adding ±1 we will have same result as above.

$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=±4^\frac 12$$
$$x=(±1)(2^2)^\frac 12$$
$$x=(±1)2^\frac 22$$
$$x=(±1)2^1$$
$$x=±2$$
but in second example we will have a negative root that leads to an imaginary number.
$$x=\sqrt4$$
$$x=±4^\frac 12$$
$$(x)^2=(±1)(4^\frac 12)^2$$
$$x^2 = (±1)4^1$$
$$x=±\sqrt4$$

Comment: No, $\sqrt{4}$ is *not* the same as $\pm 2$, because $\sqrt{4}$ is *defined* to be $2$. There is no ambiguity in the symbol $\sqrt{}$, even though $x^2 = 4$ has two solutions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out @T.Bongers

Comment: Suggested edit: "Note: In this question I am using the radical symbol to denote all roots of a number, not just the positive one". (It's more specific.)

Comment: thanks and sorry for my english @timtfj

Comment: That's fine. I hope people understand better what you're asking now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this is pretty much... wrong. Your proposition is not true.

For $x,y\>\in \Bbb R_{>0}$, $x^y$ is ***defined*** to be positive. So, as @T.Bongers pointed out, $\sqrt{4} = 2$ by definition, even if $x^2 = 4$ has exacly one positive and one negative solution. The convention for the square root is defining that it satisfies $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ for all $x$. Therefore, since for every non-negative real number $m$ there is some $m' \in \Bbb R$ such that  $m'^2 = m$,

$\sqrt{m} = |m'| \geq 0$.

Comment: i don't get if x^2 = 4 have 2 answer and x = 4^(1/2) equation didn't,and just ignore  the root symbol and please link some wiki pages so i can understand it because my english isn't that good

Comment: $x^2 = 4$ has, indeed, 2 answers. But $\sqrt m$ is different from finding the answers to $x^2 = m$. My answer has a part explaining the convention to define the square root. Take a look at it again, please.

Comment: ok i will do edit it but the main part of the question is why  x^2 = 4 have 2 answer and x = 4^(1/2) equation didn't have same answer.

Comment: Imagine John has two sons; Fred who is older and Sam who is younger.  $x^2=4$ is the like saying $x$'s father is John.  $x=\pm\sqrt{4}$ is like like saying $x$ is one of John's sons.  $x =\sqrt{4}$ is like saying $x$ is the older son of John. $x=-\sqrt{4}$ is like saying $x$ is the younger son of John. $x=\pm2$ is like saying $x$ is Fred or Sam. $x=2$ is like saying $x$ is Fred. And $x=-2$ is like saying $x$ is Sam.

Comment: @fleablood Shouldn't that amazing explanation be put in an answer to make it more visible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all $\sqrt{n}$ is defined to *always* be a single value that is *never* negative.

So if $x=\sqrt 4$ then then $x = 2$ and $x\ne -2$.

You are confusing this with

$x^2 = 4$ then $x =\pm \sqrt{4}$.  But we do not know whether $x = \sqrt 4 = 2$ or whether $x = -\sqrt{4} = -2$.  However we *DO* know that $\sqrt{4} =2$ and $\sqrt{4}$ does *NOT* equal $-2$.

However if we are told $x=\sqrt{4}$ then we are being told that $x \ne =-\sqrt{4}$.

Second, you are treating $\pm n$ as though it where a number.  It isn't a number.  It is statement that there are two possibilities to consider.  Either $n$ or $-n$.

But both have to be possible.  If we are told $x = 2$ we can't then say $x = \pm 2$ because we know $x = -2$ is not possible.  (Likewise if we are told $x = -2$ we can't say $x =\pm 2$ because we know $x=2$ is not possible.

So if we are told $x^2 = 4$ then there are  two possibilities.  Either $x = 2$ or $x = -2$ and we don't know which.  So we can say $x =\pm 2$.

If however we are told $x = \sqrt 4$ the we are given one value and we know $x = -\sqrt 4$ is not possible.

Third

whe you go from $x = 4^{\frac 12}$ to $x^2 = (4^{\frac 12})^2$ you must make a mental note that $x > 0$.  Squaring adds extranous solutions.

For example. If you have $x = 5$ and then you say $x^2 = 5^2 = 25$ you *must* remember that $x > 0$.  Then when you so $x^2 =25 \implies x =\pm \sqrt{25} = \pm 5$ you must add But ALSO $x > 0$ so $x = \sqrt{25} = 5$

So to correct everything you've done:

$x = \sqrt 4$

$x = 2$

or:

$x = \sqrt 4$

$x = 4^{\frac 12}$

$x^2 = (4^{\frac 12})^2$ (and $x > 0$)

$x^2 = 4^1$

$x = \pm \sqrt 4$ but $x > 0$ so

$x = \sqrt 4$

$x= 2$.

But:

$x = \sqrt 4$

$x = 4^{\frac 12}$

$x = (2^2)^{\frac 12}$

$x = 2^{\frac 22}$

$x = 2^1$

$x = 2$

which is basically spinning your wheels in the mud.

Comment: thanks for pointing that , but i was also confused with radical symbol itself.

Comment: The radical symbol means the *POSITIVE* square root.  All positive numbers have two square roots.  A positive square root and a negative square root. $\sqrt{x}$ refers to the *POSITIVE* one.  It does *NOT* refer to the negative one.  $-\sqrt{x}$ refers to the negative square root.

Comment: So $\sqrt{36} =6$ it does NOT equal $-6$.  ANd $-\sqrt{36}=-6$.  It does NOT equal $6$.

Comment: thanks ,but I already know most of things that community said but the main problem that make the confusing in my question that i used  radical symbol to have both the positive and the negative roots , which is wrong.